# Groupby without an aggregation function and sort that data

Tags: python-3.x

I have customer ID and date of purchase. I need to sort date of purchase for each of the customer ID seperately. 
I need a groupby operation but without an aggregation, and sort date of purchase for each customer.

Tried this way

```
new_data = data.groupby('custID').sort_values('purchase_date')
```

> AttributeError: Cannot access callable attribute 'sort_values' of
>   'DataFrameGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method

Expected result is like:

```
custID  purchase_date
100     23/01/2019
100     29/01/2019
100     03/04/2019
120     02/05/2018
120     09/03/2019
120     11/05/2019
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# import the pandas library
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'purchase_date': ['23/01/2019', '19/01/2019', '12/01/2019', '23/01/2019', '11/01/2019', '23/01/2019', '06/05/2019', '05/05/2019', '05/01/2019', '02/07/2019',],
    'custID': [100, 160, 100, 110, 160, 110, 110, 110, 110, 160]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)


sortedData = df.groupby('custID').apply(
lambda x: x.sort_values(by = 'purchase_date', ascending = True))

sortedData=sortedData.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=False)
```

**OUTPUT:**

`print(sortedData)`

```
Index  custID  purchase_date

 0     100    12/01/2019
 1     100    23/01/2019
 2     110    05/01/2019
 3     110    05/05/2019
 4     110    06/05/2019
 5     110    23/01/2019
 6     110    23/01/2019
 7     160    02/07/2019
 8     160    11/01/2019
 9     160    19/01/2019
```

`print(sortedData.to_string(index=False))`

```
custID purchase_date
 100    12/01/2019
 100    23/01/2019
 110    05/01/2019
 110    05/05/2019
 110    06/05/2019
 110    23/01/2019
 110    23/01/2019
 160    02/07/2019
 160    11/01/2019
 160    19/01/2019
```